# Silverlight Formatting Strings In Bindings With StringFormat

Tags: silverlight

I have a string of numbers stored in a string property:

```
1234567890
```

I would like the output to display:

```
(123) 456-7890
```

Can I format this in a TextBlock during binding using the StringFormat attribute? I have tried things like `stringformat='{0:(###) ###-####}'` in my binding expression without any sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The # placeholder is for use with numeric types. As far as I know, there is no placeholder character for a position in a string. To format a string, first convert it to a numeric type, then apply the formating. This requires strings of numbers only. FormatException or OverflowException may be thrown. I solved the problem by added a new property to my entity.

```
public string FormattedPhone
{
    get { return Convert.ToDouble(this.Phone).ToString("(###) ###-####"); }
}

partial void OnPhoneChanged()
{
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("FormattedPhone");
}
```

My binding then looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormattedPhone, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PhoneNumber, StringFormat='(###) ###-####'}" />
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Here is my code:`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Phone, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='(###) ###-####'}"/>` This is in a ToolTip but that shouldn't matter? Outputs:`1234567890`

Comment: Is your Phone property a string or numeric?  I tried it with a numeric (Int) property and it worked for me.  It won't work with a string property since that string format is for a numeric.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, it is a string property and yes, that's the reason why formatting cannot be applied to it. - Thanks for the response